# Looking for specific gate/dungeon manhwa

Tags: story-identification, manga

The main character has a status window. He chose multiple combat classes, like mage and healer as well as being a fighter.

At one point the he jumps into a horde of zombies from the top of a castle-like building.

There was another character in all-gold gear who is a Twitch streamer.

The manga was set in Korea.

Comment: Can you add more details? When and where did you read this, in what language? How old was it? What did the characters look like, where did it take place, what was the story about?

Comment: It took place in korea, other than that i dont know much. Its one of those typical gate/dungeon manhwas

Comment: It took place in Korea? Like Korea but with castles and zombies?

Comment: It's likely a "monsters invade earth; people get video-game like skills" type story.

Answer (score 2):

On mobile, so I can't easily post images. I am 99% sure you are talking about *[Martial God Regressed to Level 2](https://myanimelist.net/manga/161374/Martial_God_Regressed_to_Level_2)*

**Synopsis:**

> [Humanity, which has been deemed worthless, will be deleted]
>
> "Battle Net," which was thought to be a game, turned into a disaster for humankind. After the "Space League" was hosted, all living organisms in the universe fought for their lives. Humanity, represented by Earth, kept failing and was eventually annihilated. Except for one person, "Martial Saint" Jihan Seong. His skill, "Nameless Divine Arts," resisted the system's deletion. Humanity, which had been deemed worthless, received another "chance." This was the second chance granted to Jihan Seong.
>
> "Things will be different this time."
>
> Since he, the one who completed the game, had returned.